# i want to make image gallery using modal

Tags: html, css

i want to make a image gallery using modal in bootstrap , but there is a some issue and error . my gallery is not opening and its working . this is my code i'm using to make.  [this is a error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IRtQS.png)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.thumbnail').click(function(){
      $('.modal-body').empty();
    var title = $(this).parent('a').attr("title");
    $('.modal-title').html(title);
    $($(this).parents('div').html()).appendTo('.modal-body');
    $('#myModal').modal({show:true});
});
});
```

html

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <h1> Lightbox image gallery using Modal</h1>

      <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6"><a title="Image 1" href="#"><img class="thumbnail img-responsive" src="//placehold.it/600x350"></a></div>
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6"><a title="Image 2" href="#"><img class="thumbnail img-responsive" src="//placehold.it/600x350/2255EE"></a></div>
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6"><a title="Image 3" href="#"><img class="thumbnail img-responsive" src="//placehold.it/600x350/449955/FFF"></a></div>
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6"><a title="Image 4" href="#"><img class="thumbnail img-responsive" src="//placehold.it/600x350/992233"></a></div>
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6"><a title="Image 5" href="#"><img class="thumbnail img-responsive" src="//placehold.it/600x350/2255EE"></a></div>
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6"><a title="Image 6" href="#"><img class="thumbnail img-responsive" src="//placehold.it/600x350/449955/FFF"></a></div>
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6"><a title="Image 8" href="#"><img class="thumbnail img-responsive" src="//placehold.it/600x350/777"></a></div>
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6"><a title="Image 9" href="#"><img class="thumbnail img-responsive" src="//placehold.it/600x350/992233"></a></div>
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6"><a title="Image 10" href="#"><img class="thumbnail img-responsive" src="//placehold.it/600x350/EEE"></a></div>
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6"><a title="Image 11" href="#"><img class="thumbnail img-responsive" src="//placehold.it/600x350/449955/FFF"></a></div>
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6"><a title="Image 12" href="#"><img class="thumbnail img-responsive" src="//placehold.it/600x350/DDD"></a></div>
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6"><a title="Image 13" href="#"><img class="thumbnail img-responsive" src="//placehold.it/600x350/992233"></a></div>

    <hr>

    <hr>
  </div>
</div>
<div tabindex="-1" class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button class="close" type="button" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
        <h3 class="modal-title">Heading</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">

    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

css

```
.modal-dialog {width:600px;}
.thumbnail {margin-bottom:6px;}
```

Comment: The code you've posted seems to work: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3f7zxz8q/). Some possible things I can think it might be are: 1. Are you loading jQuery before the Bootstrap JS? 2. Which version of Bootstrap are you using? The example I have working is using version 3.3.7.

Comment: <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>